# How to send MMS with Gammu

Tags: sms, mms, gammu

Does anyone know how to send a Image file via Gammu?

I am trying to send an MMS Message that contains text and image via a GSM Modem connected to a Raspberry Pi 3.

I can successfully send SMS via Gammu with no problems at all. But there is very little documentation on sending MMS with Gammu.

I have read the documentation for [Gammu Utility where you can send MMS](https://wammu.eu/docs/manual/gammu/index.html?highlight=mms#cmdoption-gammu-arg-mmsindicator). But I am missing something.

I have all the details for my providers APN Proxy and Port Settings.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Please?

Comment: I have read [how-can-i-send-an-mms-via-a-gsm-gprs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397116/how-can-i-send-an-mms-via-a-gsm-gprs-modem-connected-to-a-linux-computer/16398683#16398683) but I am confused on how I make the APN Connection to send the payload to my provider. I have also read the [SIM800 series manual](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/File:SIM800_Series_AT_Command_Manual_V1.09.pdf) on how to send MMS

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I have the same question.

Comment: I sort of figured it out by not using gammu! The way I was successfull was to use Python with serial plug-in to send AT commands to the GSM Modem directly.

Comment: Which device are you using?

Comment: Do you know Python?

Comment: Where are you from? I'm in Northern Ontario, Canada

Comment: I am in Chicago and am using Huwaei E1786 which is 3G -- I've managed to get it to receive MMS. I know perl and a little bit of Python.

Comment: Did you use Gammu to receive the MMS? I tried to send but could find docs on how to make it work with MMS. If you want I can send u a copy of my python script

Comment: Kind of, gammu just downloads the hex code then I wrote a couple perl scripts that handles decoding and fetching. The python script would be great. I'll see if I can translate it to perl.

Comment: That's good. If you want a copy of my script send me your email

Comment: How can I send you my email without posting it here?

Comment: BTW, if you did this thru python you might be able to answer this python-messaging question. There's a 50 point bounty on it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54054097/python-messaging-failed-to-handle-http-request?noredirect=1#comment94948587_54054097

Comment: @Daddyfix could you share your python-script here or on pastebin? I'm trying to figure out the same thing.

Comment: @Francis You can find my code here... https://github.com/daddyfix/lte-send.py and https://github.com/daddyfix/lte-read.py