# python-messaging Failed to handle HTTP request

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, sms, mms

I am using the code below to try to send an MMS message with python-messaging https://github.com/pmarti/python-messaging/blob/master/doc/tutorial/mms.rst Although the connection seems to go smoothly I get the following response from the mmsc:

```
PROXY RESPONSE HTTP/1.0 200 OK
content-type: application/vnd.wap.mms-message
content-length: 59
Connection: close
Date: Sat, 05 Jan 2019 16:36:44 GMT
Server: Mavenir Web Application Server

���1234�����,�Failed to handle HTTP request in Mm1Server
```

Does, anyone have an idea on what the problem might be and how I can fix it? Here is my code:

```
from messaging.mms.message import MMSMessage, MMSMessagePage

mms = MMSMessage()
mms.headers['To'] = '+212XXXXXXX/TYPE=PLMN'
mms.headers['Message-Type'] = 'm-send-req'
mms.headers['Subject'] = 'Test python-messaging.mms'

slide1 = MMSMessagePage()
slide1.add_image('/home/richard/screensaver/TolleConscQte.jpg')
slide1.add_text('This first slide, is a step towards enlightenment.')

slide2 = MMSMessagePage()
slide2.set_duration(4500)
slide2.add_image('/home/richard/screensaver/TollePastALL.jpg', 1500)
slide2.add_text('This second slide is a second step towards enlightenment.', 500, 3500)

mms.add_page(slide1)
mms.add_page(slide2)

payload = mms.encode()

## sending the MMS

from cStringIO import StringIO
import socket

gw_host, gw_port = "10.188.239.143", 80 #ting

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((gw_host, gw_port))
s.send("POST %s HTTP/1.0\r\n" % "http://wholesale.mmsmvno.com/mms/wapenc")
s.send("Content-Type: application/vnd.wap.mms-message\r\n")
s.send("Content-Length: %d\r\n\r\n" % len(payload))

s.sendall(payload)

buf = StringIO()

while True:
    data = s.recv(4096)
    if not data:
        break

    buf.write(data)

s.close()
data = buf.getvalue()
buf.close()

print "PROXY RESPONSE", data
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `Host` header? And is the server you reach really an explicit HTTP proxy (not a reverse proxy)? Otherwise the full URL should not be contained after the method in the request but only the path component.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure how to add a host header but additionally I do not know if it an explicit proxy or a reverse proxy. Are you saying that the post line should be s.send("POST %s HTTP/1.0\r\n" % "/mms/wapenc") ?

Comment: Correct. And the host header should be added like the others, i.e. `s.send("Host: wholesale.mmsmvno.com\r\n")`

Comment: Thanks, but when I try:
s.send("Host: wholesale.mmsmvno.com\r\n")
s.send("POST %s HTTP/1.0\r\n" % "/mms/wapenc")
s.send("Content-Type: application/vnd.wap.mms-message\r\n")
s.send("Content-Length: %d\r\n\r\n" % len(payload)) 

I get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_sendMMS.py", line 42, in <module>
    s.sendall(payload)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Comment: A HTTP request consists of the request-line (`GET ...` etc) followed by lines with `key: value` pairs etc - you have to send the parts of the request in the correct order and not send the `Host` header before you send the request-line. See for example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages) for details.

Comment: So should s.send("Host: wholesale.mmsmvno.com\r\n") go after s.send("POST %s HTTP/1.0\r\n" % "/mms/wapenc") and before  s.send("Content-Type: application/vnd.wap.mms-message\r\n") ?

Comment: This would be more correct.

Comment: Looks like I'm back to square one. In that order I get: ���1234�����,�Failed to handle HTTP request in Mm1Server

Comment: I believe that this might be an encoding issue. Adding print, payload spits out data in this format: 250, 54, 236, 174, 205, 180, 118, 125, 106, 252, 213, 217, 183, 232, 250, 180, 125, 93, 181, 217, 217, 234, 167, 225, 216, 118, 87, 111, 213, 253, 170, 250, 123, 43, 255, 217, 1, 57, 131, 84, 104, 105, 115, 32, 115, 101, 99, 111, 110, 100, 32, 115, 108, 105, 100, 101 whereas the smil files I receive are in this format: V9#le+jC׌4}*U^ps5vl*<g߭M;zEcpwt<S

Comment: maybe instead of handling the HTTP request via socket. try using `requests` module.[link to docs](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error. The error is with the encoded MMS PDU, not the http request. I was able to get this to work by explicitly setting the From header:

```
mms.headers['From'] = ''
```

This will cause the python-messaging library to set the From header to `Insert-address-token`.

I used this [test file](https://source.puri.sm/fuzzy7k/mmsd/-/blob/simple/unit/sr-mms-mixed.mms) for debugging (just change the To phone number).

Its also fine to use a normal http client. Just make sure you are setting `Content-Type` and `Content-Length`.